# Vb.net connection timeout while generating excel report

Tags: vb.net, excel, windows-8

I am trying to generate an excel report using the data from MSSQL. It is perfectly working on my pc(server) and all clients except those PC that has windows 8 installed(MS Office 2010 installed). I tested the program in WinxP/win7 client PC's and both are able to generate the excel report(MS office 2007) installed. Is it possible that the problem is the different version of the MS Office?  Here a sample of my code. Again it is working perfectly fine on my server PC and other client PC except that win8 machine.

```
    Private Sub Report_JSIADGTAMKOR()
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim consigneeName As String
    If cmboAccount.Text = "AMKOR" Then
        consigneeName = "AMKOR"
    ElseIf cmboAccount.Text = "JSI-CIRTEK" Then
        consigneeName = "JSI-CIRTEK"
    ElseIf cmboAccount.Text = "JSI-LATTICE" Then
        consigneeName = "JSI-LATTICE"
    Else
        consigneeName = "ANALOG DEVICES GEN. TRIAS - JSI"
    End If

    Wbook = createExcel.Workbooks.Add
    Wsheet = Wbook.Worksheets(1)

    If Format(dteFrom.Value, "MM-dd-yyyy") = Format(dteTo.Value, "MM-dd-yyyy") Then
        DateRange = Format(dteTo.Value, "MM-dd-yyyy")
    Else
        DateRange = Format(dteFrom.Value, "MM-dd") & " To " & Format(dteTo.Value, "MM-dd-yy")
    End If

    Wbook.Worksheets(1).Name = cmboAccount.Text & "-SR " + DateRange.ToString

    Wsheet.Cells(1, 1).Value = "MAKATI TRANSFORWARDERS CORP."
    Wsheet.Cells(1, 1).Font.Bold = True
    Wsheet.Cells(1, 1).Font.Size = 10

    Wsheet.Cells(3, 1).Value = "Daily Status Report - " & DateRange.ToString
    Wsheet.Cells(3, 1).Font.Bold = True
    Wsheet.Cells(3, 1).Font.Size = 10

    Wsheet.Cells(5, 1).Value = consigneeName
    Wsheet.Cells(5, 1).Font.Bold = True
    Wsheet.Cells(5, 1).Font.Size = 10

    Wsheet.Cells(7, 1).Value = "Prepared by: Jasmin"
    Wsheet.Cells(7, 1).Font.Bold = True
    Wsheet.Cells(7, 1).Font.Size = 10

    Wsheet.Cells(9, 1).Value = "HAWB"
    Wsheet.Cells(9, 2).Value = "INVOICE VALUE"
    Wsheet.Cells(9, 3).Value = "DUTIABLE VALUE"
    Wsheet.Cells(9, 4).Value = "CUSTOMS DUTY"
    Wsheet.Cells(9, 5).Value = "LANDED COST"
    Wsheet.Cells(9, 6).Value = "ENTRY NO"
    Wsheet.Cells(9, 7).Value = "IP NO"
    Wsheet.Cells(9, 8).Value = "DESCRIPTION"
    Wsheet.Cells(9, 9).Value = "REMARKS"
    For Me.itemCounter = 1 To 9
        Wsheet.Cells(9, itemCounter).Font.Bold = True
    Next itemCounter

    rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    sql = "Select * From tblDocEntry Where CONVERT(datetime, DateEntry) Between '" & Format(dteFrom.Value, "MM/dd/yyyy") & "' AND '" & Format(dteTo.Value, "MM/dd/yyyy") & "' and ClientCode='" & Trim(cmboAccount.Text) & "' order by DateEntry"
    With rs
        .Open(sql, cn, CursorTypeEnum.adOpenDynamic, LockTypeEnum.adLockOptimistic)
        rowCounter = 10
        itemCounter = 1
        While .EOF = False
            Dim chkBLHAWBno As String
            chkBLHAWBno = .Fields("BLHAWBNo").Value
            Dim subHAWB As String
            subHAWB = chkBLHAWBno.ToString.Substring(0, 3)
            If IsExist("tblOmit", "OmitHAWB", subHAWB) Then
                Dim len As String = chkBLHAWBno.ToString.Trim.Length
                Wsheet.Cells(rowCounter, 3).Value = chkBLHAWBno.ToString.Substring(4, len - 4)
            Else

                Wsheet.Cells(rowCounter, 3).Value = .Fields("BLHAWBNo").Value

            End If
            Wsheet.Cells(rowCounter, 1).NumberFormat = "0000"
            Wsheet.Cells(rowCounter, 2).Value = .Fields("FMVUSD").Value
            Wsheet.Cells(rowCounter, 2).NumberFormat = "0.00"
            Wsheet.Cells(rowCounter, 3).Value = .Fields("PESOVALUE").Value
            Wsheet.Cells(rowCounter, 3).NumberFormat = "0.00"
            Wsheet.Cells(rowCounter, 4).Value = .Fields("DUTYAMOUNT").Value
            Wsheet.Cells(rowCounter, 4).NumberFormat = "0.00"
            Wsheet.Cells(rowCounter, 5).Value = .Fields("LANDEDCOST").Value
            Wsheet.Cells(rowCounter, 5).NumberFormat = "0.00"
            Wsheet.Cells(rowCounter, 6).Value = .Fields("ENTRYNO").Value
            Wsheet.Cells(rowCounter, 7).Value = .Fields("IPNO").Value
            Wsheet.Cells(rowCounter, 8).Value = Trim(.Fields("GoodDesc").Value)
            Wsheet.Cells(rowCounter, 9).Value = .Fields("DOCREMARKS").Value
            rowCounter = rowCounter + 2
            itemCounter = itemCounter + 1
            .MoveNext()
        End While
        .Close()
    End With
    rs = Nothing

    Wsheet.Cells(rowCounter + 1, 1).Value = "Total Number of Entry/ies: " & (itemCounter - 1)
    Wsheet.Cells(rowCounter + 2, 1).Value = "Date Printed: " + Format(Now, "MM/dd/yyyy") + " - " + Format(Now, "hh:mm:ss tt")
    Wsheet.Cells(rowCounter + 1, 1).Font.Bold = True
    Wsheet.Cells(rowCounter + 2, 1).Font.Bold = True
    Wsheet.Columns.AutoFit()
    Wsheet.Rows.AutoFit()
    'Wsheet.Cells.NumberFormat = "0000"
    filesavepath = AppPath & "\Status Reports\" & Trim(cmboAccount.Text) & " - Status Report " + DateRange.ToString + ".xls"
    Wbook.SaveAs(filesavepath)
    Wbook.Close(True)
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(filesavepath)
    Wbook = Nothing
    Wsheet = Nothing
    MsgBox("Report Successfully Generated", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "System Alert")
End Sub
```

The error thrown is something like these: 
"Connection Timeout Expired: The timeout period elapsed during the post-login phase. The connection could have timed out while waiting for server to complete the login process and respond. Or it could have timed out while attempting to create multiple active connections."

Any help regarding my problem would be much appreciated

Comment: Try increasing time out time http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175136.aspx

Comment: @Damith Doesn't work for me. Again my problem is just on a win8 machine, other client PC running xp/win7 don't have this issue at all.

Answer (score 0):

No one can give you exact answer why it happens unless trying it in the hard way.

Generally i suggest you to take more actions to debug it through, to identify:

1. is it a sql connection problem?

   - Could it be due to the Win 8 box blocked the sql connection get through? firewall?
   - what's the size of the expected data from sql? Could it be the Win 8 machine have some anti-virus software scanning the incoming data that slows down the process?
2. is it due to excel writing process taking too long?

   - I can see you update excel file cell by cell, actually there are better ways to speed it up significantly, you could ask google for fast writing to excel through interop
   - data size - could it happen that there are too many rows to write into the file and it takes ages?

You may put more breakpoints or some logging statements to dig out the actual cause, and then work around that.

Comment: I was able to solve my problem yesterday. I just remembered that the test server I am using is MSSQL 2005 which has compatibility issue with win8. I forgot to change the connection string and let it connect to the serverPC which has MSSQL 2010. So yeah the win8 computer trying to connect to MSSQL 2005 is causing the problem. thanks for your suggestions though